# Generic way to convert a string into a numerical type?

Tags: c++, string, generics, types, casting

I have this class:

```
template<typename T> class Parser
{
    public:
        Parser() : count(0) {}
        virtual void parse(const string&);
        void get_token(void);
    private:
        T result;
        char token;
        string expression;
        int count;
};
```

now had the class not been generic, had the `result` been say, a `double`, I would have used this method to detect numbers.

```
while((strchr("1234567890.",token))
{
     /* add token to a "temp" string */
     /* etc. etc. */
}

result = atof(temp.c_str());
```

But since `result` is generic, I can't use any method like `atof` and `atoi` etc.

What do I do?

Comment: ¤ You can use a `std::istringstream`. Or you can use a `boost::lexical_cast`, which uses the stream internally. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Xeo: Hardly. Related, though.

Comment: @Lightness: Yeah, after rereading, I noticed it missed the "generic" part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boost has this functionality built-in:

```
 #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

 void Parser<T>::get_token() {
     std::string token = ...;
     result = boost::lexical_cast<T>(token);
 }
```

Add exception handling as required.

---

Or, perhaps you don't want to use Boost for some reason:

```
void Parser<T>::get_token() {
     std::string token = ...;

     std::stringstream ss;
     ss << token;
     ss >> result;
}
```

Check the error state of `ss` as required.

---

More expansive answers may be found on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c), though it discusses only `int` specifically.

Comment: +1, Thanks. I'd rather not add boost to my project, so I'll go with `stringstream`

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: You only need a header. That's it. The `boost` solution is _far_ more robust. Please consider it again.

Comment: (If you're writing a parser, I'm baffled that you're not using Boost already!)

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: When writing a parser, I'd resort to a parser generator. Boost.Spirit is pretty awesome in that aspect.

Comment: @Xeo Yes, I would have done that if I was like, building a parser for serious work, like a professional programming language / script etc. But I'm actually trying to learn how recursive descent parsers etc. are implemented. Therefore I think, writing from scratch would teach me more.

Answer (score 1):

Another generic template based Numeric To String converter. It takes `int`s and `double`s.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
inline std::string Numeric_To_String (const T& t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
return ss.str();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i = 9;
   double d = 1.2345;
   string s;

  cout <<"Generic Numeric_To_String( anyDatatype ) \n\n";

  s = Numeric_To_String( i );
  cout <<"int i to string    : "<< s <<"   "<< endl; 

  s = Numeric_To_String( d );
  cout <<"double d to string : "<< s <<"   "<< endl;
  cout <<" \n";   

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a hand full of types you want to parse, you can use template specialization:

```
template<>
void Parser<int>::parse(const string&)
{
    result = atoi(string.c_str());
}

template<>
void Parser<float>::parse(const string&)
{
    result = atof(string.c_str());
}
```

...
But this only works if you implement every convertion you need, of course.

Comment: Regarding `atoi` and `atof` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892951/list-of-deprecated-c-functions. Also you need to use _named_ parameters; `string.c_str()` isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

With C++17 you can use the templated `std::from_chars`.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars

```
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Number>
auto stringTo(std::string_view str)
{
    Number number;
    std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), number);
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    const auto str = std::string("42");
    std::cout << stringTo<long>(str) << '\n';
    std::cout << stringTo<double>(str) << '\n'; 
}
```

Check the return value of `std::from_chars` to detect errors.

```
const auto result = std::from_chars(...);
if (result.ec == std::errc::invalid_argument || result.ec == std::errc::result_out_of_range)
{
   std::cout << "string to number error" << '\n';
}
```

More info and examples: https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/12/fromchars.html

GCC and clang don't yet support the floating point version of `std::from_chars` (August 2019).