# How do I fix scanf? (FailSafes)

Tags: c, function, loops, selection, scanf

Here i have a simplified piece of code that asks and displays a number on a loop, it works fine for all numbers i type in, But if i input a letter or a special character (!"£$%^&*-_=+ etc ) it goes mental and skips the input.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int number; 
 int main()
 {
     do
     {
     system("cls");
     printf("Enter a number");
     scanf("%d",&number);
     }
     while(1==1);
}
```

My question is, what can i do to stop this from happening?, is there some code that filters out this nonsense or is scanf pretty much worthless?

//Edit: This is somehow been marked as a duplicate, heh.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1253080/2436175

Comment: `scanf` returns a value, why not just check this, as you should do for all C library functions anyhow?

Comment: @JensGustedt That requires an extra library, 1==1 is simple and straight to the point.

Comment: @WhipItOut Just `1` is more simpler

Comment: @JensGustedt Checked the value, if a correct int value was entered before, it's that, if not, it's 0

Comment: @WhipItOut, this is hilarious. `stdbool.h` is not a library but just an include file, meant to make your code easier to read. If you don't want to use `true` since you know what you are doing use `1` as Gopi suggests.

Comment: @CoolGuy While(1)? Sure but coming back to this i'll be confused thinking it something like, 1 iteration of the code or whatever, i think 1==1 is better.

Comment: @WhipItOut, you didn't check well enough. The manual page for `scanf` has more information that could be useful for you.

Comment: @JensGustedt #Inlcude,stdbool.h> is what i call a library. Now, perhaps you would like to help rather than pick out minor differences in our coding techniques?

Comment: If you don't understand C well enough to know what `while(1)` is doing, you definitively should use `true`.

Comment: @JensGustedt I took 2 inputs into my code, the correct integer and the incorrect alphabetical character. What other checks could i possibly do?

Comment: @JensGustedt I understand C enough to know that a while loop requires an operator in order to stop it. It's just good practice that i include one, even for a infinite loop.

Comment: 1) check the return value from `scanf()` to determine its success, if not as expected (1), do not use `number`.  Code needs to read the offending data in a different manner.  2) Do not use `scanf()`, use `fgets()`, then `sscanf()` the input string.

Comment: @JensGustedt LOL you mad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` with `%d` will fail to scan an integer and returns 0 when a character was entered. So just check if it doesn't return 1. If it doesn't , a character was entered (if it returned 0) or else, an integer was entered. Note that if `EOF` was encountered, `scanf` will return -1.

```
if(scanf("%d", &number) != 1)//character entered
{
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    scanf("%*s");//clear the invalid character(s) from stdin
}
else
{
    //a number was entered
}
```

The reason that `scanf` becomes "mental" and the program prints `Enter a number` many times when you enter a character is that when the `scanf` fails to scan an integer from the standard input stream(`stdin`), it returns 0 and the execution continues. When `scanf` is called the next time, it sees the characters which you had entered the last time and again fails and this process continues. To prevent it, just clear the `stdin` like I've done in the code above.

Another popular way of clearing the `stdin` is using:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i wrote a thank you on your post because there was a glitch with the commenting. Anyway, it works, thank you

Comment: Check for EOF. scanf(...) greater than 0 for success. If it returns 0 then the string is improperly formatted. If less than zero then it's come to the end of the file or encountered an error reading.

Comment: @SamuelDanielson Thank You. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1253080/2436175):

> if the input doesn't conform to the expected format `scanf()` can be
>   impossible to recover sensibly [..] A "better" alternative here is to
>   use an input function like `fgets()` or `fgetc()` to read chunks of input,
>   then scan it with `sscanf()` or parse it with string handling functions
>   like `strchr()` and `strtol()`.

Comment: I thought fgets() was reserved for string input?

Comment: @WhipItOut Before becoming (for example) a number, any keyboard input is a string.