# Memory allocation in C - Acronyms :)

Tags: c

[image: Example of the input/output]

Please see the code below. The user should enter a sentence and the code should return the acronyms of the sentence.

However, when I allocate *str and define N as 1.

"three letter acronym" >> should be >> "t"

In real time, "three letter acronym" >> is >> "tla"

This doesn't make sense.
Please explain why this happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 1
#define M 35

char *acronyms (char *st,  char *sentence);

int main()
{

char *str=(char*)(malloc(N*sizeof(char)));
char *sen=(char*)(malloc(M*sizeof(char)));

printf("enter... ");
gets(sen);
puts(acronyms(str, sen));

free(str);
free(sen);
    return 0;
}


char *acronyms (char *st,  char *sentence)
{
     char *p = st;
     char *q = sentence;

     if (*q !=' ') {
            *p =*q;
            p++;
     }

     while (*(q+1)) {
         if (*q==' '  &&  *(q+1)!= ' ') {
             *p = *(q+1);
             p++;
         }

        q++;
     }
     *p='\0';
     return st;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a better input/output sample?

Comment: http://commadot.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wtf.png

Comment: Don't forget the `'\0'` when you `malloc()`. If you need space for a one character string, you must alloc 2 bytes. And never use `gets()` but `fgets()`

Comment: and nowhere in `acronyms()` the number of words taken into account is limited to `N`

Comment: but why does the program does not quit? or fail?

Comment: Please show us your plain text as text instead of graphics.

Comment: `char *str=(char*)(malloc(N*sizeof(char)));` allocates only one single byte. So the only string that can be stored there is the empty string. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: Ok, you're right. so why doesn't it show an empty string?

Comment: _but why does the program does not quit or fail?_ and _so why doesn't it show an empty string?_ Because once you've written beyond allocated memory, you enter the realm "undefined behaviour" (google that term), and then anything can happen.

Comment: To write a string containing one ASCII character, allocate memory for 2 bytes, one for the character, the next for the NULL terminator.  (or just create `char str[2];`)

Comment: @ryyker as far as I understood he wants to enter e.g. _What the f@#k_ and get _Wtf_ as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not seem very satisfying at first glance, but once you have an understanding of the underlying principles pointed to by these 5 concepts (each with example(s)),this, and other similar tasks will seem much simpler.

Necessary steps to do what you are trying:

1) Understand console user input techniques (*[Good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4023921/645128)*)
2) Understand definition of string ( *[Good definition,explanation here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)*. )
3) Understand usage of `[c][m]alloc(...)` (*[Good discussion here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc)* ...)
3a) ...and when to use it. or not. ( *[heap vs. stack memory](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)* )
4) Understand string parsing techniques. ( *[ex 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9210528/645128)* , *[ex 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/274477/General-string-parsing-techniques)*, *[ex 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=05xA_d5dSwAC&pg=PA565&lpg=PA565&dq=C+string+parsing+techniques&source=bl&ots=3Pry5BgaOb&sig=KrAnYK3fW-vrRTMJsxsVH8nm9Qw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimyrrHiNrYAhUIS5AKHfUpAxIQ6AEIRDAD#v=onepage&q=C%20string%20parsing%20techniques&f=false)* )
5) Become aware of legal, but unwise techniques, such as using *[gets](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gets-is-risky-to-use/)*, or *[in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253053/cs-bad-functions-vs-their-good-alternatives/1253079#1253079)*.

These are generally applicable techniques, useful for many tasks that include user input and string manipulation, but are not a good replacement for referring to a good C book to provide a necessary foundation in the basics.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not use `gets()`. Why?? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

You are allocating only `1` byte of memory to `str`:

```
char *str=(char*)(malloc(N*sizeof(char)));
```

and in function `acronyms()`, you are writing beyond the allocated memory. This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To get the acronym of input sentence, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define STR_LEN 100

char *acronyms (char *pstr,  char *str_acronym);

int main(void) {

    char input_str[STR_LEN];
    char *sen = NULL;

    printf ("Enter:\n");
    fgets (input_str, STR_LEN, stdin);

    sen = malloc (strlen(input_str) + 1);
    if (sen == NULL) {
            perror ("Failed to allocate memory");
            return -1;
    }

    puts (acronyms(input_str, sen));

    free(sen);

    return 0;
}

char * acronyms(char *pstr,  char *str_acronym)
{
    int count = 0, add = 1;

    for (int i = 0; pstr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (isspace(pstr[i])) {
                    add = 1;
                    continue;
            }
            if (add) {
                    str_acronym[count] = pstr[i];
                    count++;
                    add = 0;
            }
    }
    str_acronym[count] = '\0';

    return str_acronym;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in the code:

1) allocating only one byte for the string `str`:

```
#define N 1
char *str=(char*)(malloc(N*sizeof(char)));
```

2) using `gets(sen)` instead of    `fgets(sen,M+1,stdin);`

3) `char *acronyms (char *st,  char *sentence)`
has very problematic logic. The end of string is not recognized, the `' '` may or may not be present:

```
 if (*q !=' ') {
        *p =*q;
        p++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wellcome in the world of Undefined Behaviour! When you use an array out of its bonds, anything can happen **including expected result**. That's what happens here: you allocate 1 single byte for str, and write 5 `{'h', 'a, 'n', 'd', '\0'}`. [Un]fortunately, at a lower level it looks like you only overwrite unused memory, and actually get your result.

Simply as it is UB, you cannot rely on that, and same source compiled in a different environement could SEGFAULT or print nothing with the exact same input.

And as you have been told in comment [**don't use `gets`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)