# Allocating memory to an array and changing a value in

Tags: arrays, c

I have written very simple code, that I used to feel confident in but it isn't working. I don't know if I am doing anything wrong or perhaps it is something wrong with my vscode. I have allocated memory for an array of integers and chars, and I then use scanf to read values that I then want to save in said arrays. But it appears it is saving the values as garbage value when I use printfs to debug.

*For context: tamanhos = sizes, which are supposed to be either p, P, g or G, and quantidades are supposed to be integers*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define professores 7
int main () {
    int quantidade, total, holder;
    char tamanho;

    total = 0;

    int * quantidades = (int*)malloc(professores*sizeof(int));
    char * tamanhos = (char*)malloc(professores*sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        scanf(" %d", &quantidade);
        scanf(" %c", &tamanho);
        quantidades[i] = quantidade;
        tamanhos[i] = tamanho;
    }

    printf("%d", total);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ){
        if (tamanhos[i] == "P" || tamanhos[i] == "p") {
            holder = quantidades[i];
            total = total + quantidades[i]*10;
        }
        else if (tamanhos[i] == "G" || tamanhos[i] == "g") {
            total = total + quantidades[i]*16;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
    int xprof = total / 7;
    printf("%d", xprof);

    free(quantidades);
    free(tamanhos);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note, use `professores` instead of hard coding `7` in the loop controls and divisor.

Comment: Also avoid casting the output of malloc (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I see the problem with your code.  Your scanf statements are using the & operator.  The result is instead of *quantidades, you're getting **quantidades which is a pointer to a pointer.  Remove the & and it should work properly.  The & is the address of operator and it provides the memory address of the associated item.  Since your variables are already pointers, there's no need to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem:

- `tamanhos[i] == "P"` compares a `char` to "pointer to a string literal". You probably meant to use single quotes, i.e. `tamanhos[i] == 'P'`.

Minor points of improvement:

- `int main()` is, generally, not a valid signature for this function, use `int main(void)` when not using the parameters.
- The magic number `7` appears several times. Perhaps these should be replaced by the macro `professores`? The latter is commonly written in all caps to distinguish it from a regular variable.
- A value is stored in `holder`, but this is never read.
- Try to declare and initialize variables in one statement (e.g. `int n = 5`), unless you are using an old version of C which does not allow this.
- Try to make the scope of the variables as small as possible. Simply put, declare them directly before they are used.
- The function `scanf` can be tricky to use w.r.t. avoiding buffer overflows. It is best replaced by a combination of `fgets` followed by `sscanf` (or parsing the result manually).
- You can write values directly to an array, e.g. `scanf(" %d", &quantidades[i]);`.

*Additional credits: Oka and Andrew Henle.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. What do you recommend using instead of scanf?

Comment: @JOAOVITORPEREIRAVENTURA You're welcome. Search for `scanf` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253053/what-makes-a-c-standard-library-function-dangerous-and-what-is-the-alternative) for an alternative and broader discussion. If you must use `scanf`, then it's best to also check its return value to see if the read was successful.

Comment: Calling `scanf` *generally not safe* is misleading. Some precautions must be taken to limit input lengths when attempting to read strings (`%s`, `%[]`), but mainly `scanf` is just very tricky to use, rather than unsafe, with many pitfalls surrounding common tasks. The most commonly suggested alternative is to read partial/entire lines with `fgets`, and parse them manually or with `sscanf`, which gives you more robust control when parsing and handling bad input.

Comment: @Oka True, true. It's not _always_ unsafe, but there's a reason it's considered deprecated in C11 by, e.g., Clang's analyzer. I'll update the answer.

Comment: *In C11, it is best replaced by `scanf_s`...*  [IMO, no it should not be](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm), unless you want to write *de facto* non-portable code that is not any more secure.  The real problem with `scanf()` is that it leaves your input stream in an unknown state if a failure occurs so `fgets()` then `sscanf()` is IMO the only real solution.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you. I was under the impression that these functions were [part of C11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), but I now see that it is only optional and poorly supported. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In C and in C++ single quotes identify a single character, while double quotes create a string literal. You are compairing character so use single quotes instesd of double.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define professores 7
int main () {
    int quantidade, total = 0, holder;
    char tamanho;    
    int * quantidades = (int*)malloc(professores*sizeof(int));
    char * tamanhos = (char*)malloc(professores*sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        scanf(" %d", &quantidade);
        scanf(" %c", &tamanho);
        quantidades[i] = quantidade;
        tamanhos[i] = tamanho;
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ){
        if (tamanhos[i] == 'P' || tamanhos[i] == 'p') {
            holder = quantidades[i];
            total = total + quantidades[i]*10;
        }
        else if (tamanhos[i] == 'G' || tamanhos[i] == 'g') 
            total = total + quantidades[i]*16;
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
    int xprof = total / 7;
    printf("%d", xprof);

    free(quantidades);
    free(tamanhos);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code here...

```
scanf(" %d", &quantidade);
scanf(" %c", &tamanho);
```

don't use spaces in `scanf(" %d, &quantidade);`

and also you can insert values in the array directly like...

```
scanf("%d", &quantidades[i]);
scanf("%c", &tamanhos[i]);
```

If I am not wrong then your compiler must be giving you a warning here...

```
if (tamanhos[i] == "P" || tamanhos[i] == "p") {
```

and here..

```
else if (tamanhos[i] == "G" || tamanhos[i] == "g") {
```

You are comparing a single character here only so use only single colon...